# Detox textInput not writing text

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, jestjs, detox

I am using Detox on my react-native project and want to input a name on the login screen, but detox is not recognising the textInput. 
This is my text code

```
describe('SCA', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should have splash screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('splash'))).toBeVisible();
  });
  it('should show login screen', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id('login'))).toBeVisible();
  });
  it('test login screen name input', async () => {
    await element(by.id('name')).typeText('Liam')
  });
});
```

The textInput code:

```
<TextInput
        testID="name"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ name: value }) }
        placeholder={'Name ... '}
        placeholderTextColor='white'
        value={name} />
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
 ● SCA › test login screen name input

    Failed: [Error: Error: Cannot find UI element.
    Exception with Action: {
      "Action Name":  "Type 'Liam'",
      "Element Matcher":  "((!(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('name'))) || (((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && parentThatMatches((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('name'))))))",
      "Recovery Suggestion":  "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
    }


    Error Trace: [
      {
        "Description":  "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
        "Error Domain":  "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code":  "0",
        "File Name":  "GREYElementInteraction.m",
        "Function Name":  "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
        "Line":  "124"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re currently reloading the device between each test.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  await device.reloadReactNative();
});
```

I don’t think that is what you want to do as it resets everything meaning you have to wait for everything to reload and move through your screens and you will face the same issue that you did in your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875453/detox-only-testing-splash-screen) (NB your usage of `waitFor` is incorrect, see my answer on your previous post or re-read the [documentation](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.waitFor.md))

You can read more about `.typeText` in the [documentation](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#typetexttext).

A common mistakes when using `.typeText` is not disconnecting the hardware keyboard

> Note: Make sure hardware keyboard is disconnected. Otherwise, Detox may fail when attempting to type text.
>
> To make sure hardware keyboard is disconnected, open the simulator from Xcode and make sure Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard is deselected (or press ⇧⌘K).

One thing I always do when using `.typeText` is make sure that the element exists

So I would add the following before you use `.typeText` to make sure that it is visible.

```
await expect(element(by.id('name'))).toBeVisible();
```

Comment: yes this worked, changed keyboard settings and kept it within the reloadReactNative() thank you